# Magento 2 Product Detail Page Image is not display it is Loading

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

In my site product, details page image is not displayed still it will be loading. How to find out about this problem. Can you please help me? please find the screenshot https://prnt.sc/kdcff2

Comment: Is that any console error ?

Comment: @dileep kumar, can you attach console screenshot for more detail

Comment: Please run flush cache command and reload the page. If still same please check for console error.

Comment: Hi @ Kanhaiya lal,  Please find the link http://prntscr.com/kdct35

Comment: Hi @ Jafar, I have run the flush cache command and it doesn't display image still it will be loading Please find the console link prntscr.com/kdct35

Comment: Are you using any custom theme? or is it Luma theme?